# how to get first value from the word entered in the input (only first letter)

Tags: jquery, text, input

I know that this question is so noob . but I want to know that how to get the first letter from the entered word in an input text.

I don't know about it .but please guide me about that .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The native Javascript [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method can do that:

```
var firstChar = $('#textbox').val().substr(0, 1);
```

The first argument is the character position to start from, the second is the length to take.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 2):

You can use charAt to get the first letter.

```
var x = 'some text';
alert(x.charAt(0));
```

If you're using jQuery and have a textbox with id="firstName" you can access the first letter in the following way.

```
var firstLetter = $("#firstName").val().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var value =$('#input').val();
var firstLetter=value.substring(1, value.length);
```